# Unresolved external symbol. C++

Tags: c++, qtwebkit, qt5

When I try to compile my test app it fails.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.8 )
project( webkit-test )

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package( Qt5Core )
find_package( Qt5Gui )
find_package( Qt5OpenGL )
find_package( Qt5Network )
find_package( Qt5WebKit )
find_package( Qt5Widgets )

add_executable( webkit-test main.cpp )

qt5_use_modules( webkit-test Core Gui OpenGL Network WebKit Widgets )
```

C++ code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebView>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        QString file;
        if ( argc >= 2 )
                file = argv[1];

        QApplication a( argc, argv );

        return a.exec();
}
```

I generate makefile by `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"` [(3)](http://pastebin.com/uDGBx4S7) and then use `nmake` [(4)](http://pastebin.com/vwJZk7JD).

After I received that I used `dumpbin /EXPORTS QtWebKit5.dll > QtWebKit5.dll.exports.txt` and `dumpbin /EXPORTS QtWebKit5.lib > QtWebKit5.lib.exports.txt` for seeing to exporting symbols: [(5)](http://pastebin.com/gmubayWB) and [(6)](http://pastebin.com/7A4c1Seh).

By using Ctrl+F you can find in these files "unresolved" external symbols:

> ?staticMetaObject@QWebPage@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const QWebPage::staticMetaObject)
>
> ?staticMetaObject@QWebView@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const QWebView::staticMetaObject)

If symbols are in QtWebKit5.lib, why I have these errors when linking?

Comment: I've replaced your links and improved some of the markup, but you should really consider putting at least the code from (1) and (2) directly in your question, the files are tiny and it will make it much more likely people will look at them than if they have to follow links to pastebin

Comment: How do you link with QtWebKit5.lib?

Comment: It looks like you have a header included but it can't find the associated library.

Comment: stark, cmake finds that library and use this path in makefile.

Comment: mydogisbox, nmake knows where is QtWebKit5.lib. I tried show the path to that lib in CMakeLists.txt for confidence. Error were the same.

Comment: I was just saying what the error was.  I don't know why you're getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `add_definitions(-DQT_DLL)` to my CMakeLists.txt and now it's compiled.

Answer (score 2):

some reasons affect to this,

if you use Qt with version greater than 4.7, add this namespace to your project's ".pro" file:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

and if less equals than 4.7:

```
QT += webkit
```

and change your **QWebView** library to (if gets a warning about "No such file or directory" do not worry!)

```
#include <QwebView>
```